# Get number of databases in an Azure Elastic Pool

Tags: c#, sql, database, azure, nuget

Is there an way to find how many databases there is in Azure Elastic pool. we will have 5 and i some cases needs to know if it full. I have looked in the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql nuget package, but i cant find a way to do this

Comment: Could you use REST and call the [Azure endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/listbyserver)

Comment: I can use the ListByElasticPool og then count on the reslut

Comment: Yes, for some reason I copied the wrong link. This is what I was I wanted to show you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/listbyelasticpool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure's REST API to fetch information from your Elastic Pool.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/elasticPools/{elasticPoolName}/databases?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

Just follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/listbyelasticpool) from Microsoft's documentation.